# Print even and odd lines from file

Tags: java, list, sorting, data-structures

I am trying to read from a file, then print the even elements first, followed by the odd lines. Is it best to read the lines and store them in a list for even and another for odd then print each? Or is there a more efficient way around this?

the snippet of code below, is the method in which i am doing this sorting... As of now, it simply stores the input into a list and prints them. Is there an efficient way to print even lined words followed by odd numbered lines?

```
public static void test(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();

    String line;
    int n = 0;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        s.add(line);
        n++;
    }
    Iterator<String> i = s.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        w.println(i.next());
    }
}
```

thanks in advance for any help/input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your best bet is to print the even lines as you read them, and store the odd lines for later printing.

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();

String line;
int n = 0;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    if(n % 2 == 0){
        s.add(line);
    }
    else{
        w.println(line);
    }
    n++;
}
Iterator<String> i = s.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    w.println(i.next());
}
```

That will half the amount of space required. Another option might be to print the odd lines to a string, then print that value to the output stream - might be more efficient for shorter inputs

Comment: would that print odd numbers first? If so, can that if/else be swapped so that even lines are printed first?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "odd" it will add the 0th line to the array, and print the 1st, which in terms of an actual file means, storing the odd number rows and printing the even numbered rows. It just happens that we are starting from index 0, not 1. But yes, swapping the if condition (or doing %2 == 1) will give the opposite effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your loop as follows:

```
while (i.hasNext()) {
    String odd = i.next();
    if (i.hasNext()) {
        String even = i.next();
        w.println(even);
        w.println(odd);
    } else {
        w.println(odd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For small files what you're doing is fine - just iterate over your list twice printing alternate lines, evens on the first pass, odds on the second.

For large files, read the file twice and print alternate lines as before. What's a large file? That's system dependent.